# What is this sprawling vine with green leaves?

Tags: identification

The attached photos were taken in a friends garden yesterday.
Can anyone help identify it please[image]
The picture was taken in Watford Herts UK at back of garden adjacent to wasteland.

Comment: With [tag:identification] questions, it's useful to describe the plant in as much detail as you can, where in the world you found the plant, and the conditions where you found it (sun, shade, rocky hillside, forested riverbank, and so on). If you have more information about the plant, please update your question to add it. Thanks!

Comment: It looks almost like bittersweet, but the leaves aren't quite right. They are too squat and short.

Answer (score 7):

It's **[Hedera Helix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedera_helix)**, common or English ivy.

What you see here is the "mature" shape of the leaves.

Young plants have the typical "ivy-shaped" leaves and the flattish, creeping/climbing appearance we all know:[image: juvenile]

But once the plant has reached a certain age / size, the top part grows "bushy", leaf shape is different and flowers / berries appear:[image: adult]

Here is a photo I took today of an ivy in the transitional stage. Note the flat leaves on the lower part of the trunk and the mature branches in the upper part:

[image: juvenile/adult]

Comment: @mick: You are welcome! Did you already check out our [help section](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help)? I'd especially like to point you to [asking](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/asking) in general and specifically to [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).